# How can username be received by an upstream private service from a OAuth2-proxy?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, proxy, oauth2-proxy

I set up [OAuth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) as a reverse proxy, providing authentication and authorization for users of a custom web application, deployed as an upstream private service. It all works well. Except that I would like to pass the username from the reverse proxy to the upstream application.

[The OAuth2-proxy documentation](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview/) suggests that username can be passed from the reverse proxy as the HTTP header **X-Forwarded-User**. But how can my upstream application receive that HTTP header? The upstream application is in Python, so I looked at the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) package, but that package seems to only provide headers for an outbound request made by the application, or the response to that outbound request.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, with [some help](https://community.render.com/t/how-to-get-oauth2-authenticated-email-from-within-private-service/5584/2?u=bridgeland) from someone on the Render forum.

The HTTP header **X-Forwarded-Email** carries the user's email from OAuth2-proxy to the upstream application. The upstream application is in [Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/), which runs on top of [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/).  The headers are available via **flask.request.headers**.